# plotly candlestick in python with flag

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, candlestick-chart

I set up a candlestick chart using plotly and would like to know if you can create on top of that chart based on the flag column containing the number 1, a rectangle that overlaps candlesticks

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({"data_minu": ['30/10 09:00','30/10 09:05','30/10,09:10','30/10 09:15','30/10 09:20','30/10 09:25','30/10 09:30','30/10 09:35','30/10 09:40','30/10 09:45'],
                   "Open":['10','17','23','20','8','22','24','25','29','22'],
                   "High":['21','27','25','29','24','27','28','32','29','25'],
                   "Low":['6','12','18','9','5','8','24','18','15','10'],
                   "Close":['17','24','22','10','21','25','26','30','18','10'],
                   "Flag": ['0','1','1','1','0','1','1','1','0','0']})     

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['data_minu'],
                open=df['Open'], high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'], close=df['Close'])
                     ])  

fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)    
fig.show()
```

**Current result:**

[image]

**Outline for desired result:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Your attempt to include a sample dataframe is highly appreciated, but your code snippet as it now stands does not work. `insira o código aqui` is that portuguese?

Comment: Yes sorry. I will see how to include it correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

. The people on the plotly website helped me with this question. I share their answer and on top of it to make various adjustments.

https://community.plot.ly/t/plotly-candlestick-in-python-with-flag/31154

Thanks .